# How Does the 'Open' Column (#open) Impact Lightning Experience Reports & Dashboards in SolarBot High-Case Candidates Report?

Tags: salesforce-lightning

I'm currently pursuing the Lightning Experience Reports & Dashboards Specialist badge, and an intriguing aspect arose during the creation of the SolarBot High-Case Candidates report.

In alignment with the requirements, I was tasked with adding a column indicating whether a case is open or closed. Despite an initial struggle in finding a solution, I eventually noticed the presence of an "open" column (#open) within the case. This column effectively communicates whether a case is open or closed. After conducting internet research, I concluded that this feature is a customization or a specific implementation within a certain context.

[image]

I'm struggling to comprehend the functionality of `#open` and how it is assigning values. Despite my efforts to investigate, I have not found any corresponding field, validation rule, or trigger defined on the Case object.

[image]
[image]
[image]